# Вопрос по функциям С++

Tags: c++, функции

Почему нельзя написать функцию в функции С++?

Comment: Почему это нельзя? Очень даже можно.

Comment: приведите пример когда у вас не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы язык хотя бы указывайте
например, питон:

```
def test(a):
    def test2(b):
        return b * 10

    return test2(a)

print(test(11))
```